# Large data not saved in a text of varchar column of a postgresql table

Tags: pgadmin

DataType problem?

I want to store a large json value in a postgresql table. The column on which I have to store the large data was first text datatype and then varchar(1048576) but the large data is not saved in it. Only large data is not saved.

```
{
         "name": "title_font_family",
         "value": "data:application/font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,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"
},
```

The value is 181598 character but I entered here only a part becouse the body limit of the stackoverflow post is 30000.

So, no error is thrown. The only thing is that data is not saved.
[image]

Comment: There is a limit to the length of data displayed in pgadmin guis - are you sure the data isn't stored? What happens if you query from psql directly?

Comment: I changed the number of characters to display like in the duplicate question and also I disabled the option to display limited nr of characters but the data is still not visible directly.